# How to use WebRTC + Pubnub Api for video chat client in Native ios8 app swift 2.0

Tags: swift, pubnub, videochat

I am working on a iOS 8 application with the functionality of p2p video chat just like Skype. while researching on google, I got some libraries but not getting anything for iOS 8 native.

I decided to go with WebRTC with the use of PubNub API. How can I create a video chat native iOS client with the use of these libraries?

I found one code for native video chat client,

https://www.pubnub.com/docs/cocoa-swift/pubnub-swift-sdk

I don't understand this demo application.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: Probably because iOS development is pretty much a lost cause nowadays. People are moving away from the closed ecosystems to capitalize on software-as-service, micro-payments .etc rather than depend on platform controlled advertisements for revenue.

Comment: Not that I have anything against Apple. Actually, I love their products. It's just that it's the industry trend.

Comment: in that tutorial saied that all code in appdelegate.swift but i dont know what im doing in other viewcontroller?? @abarisone

Comment: You will need more than PubNub for video chat as PubNub plays the role of *signal protocol* but not the media streamer service. Please see [this PubNub KB article to get a full understanding of WebRTC and PubNub's role](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/252/does-pubnub-support-webrtc-and-video-chat).

Comment: Hi @T.Parsa Did u implement this? could you please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PubNub as a Signal Protocol for WebRTC

You will need more than PubNub for video chat as PubNub plays the role of signal protocol but not the media streamer service. [Please see this PubNub KB article to get a full understanding of WebRTC and PubNub's role](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/252/does-pubnub-support-webrtc-and-video-chat).